# Spring 5.2.x to 5.3.x upgrade cause ClassNotFoundException for Quartz Jobs under Wildlfy 20

Tags: spring, wildfly, classloader, quartz

We are using:

JDK 8

Spring 5.2.16.RELEASE

Quartz - 2.3.2

Wildfly 20

Apart from the web application(.war) we have also plugins (.jar) for which the classes are loaded with the following code in the web app:

```
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(pluginsClassLoader);
```

`PluginsClassLoader extends URLClassLoader`

We are using
`org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzBean` to define our own quartz jobs both in the war in the plugins (.jar) e.g. `FSSendMessagesWorker extends QuartzBean`

in a @Configuration class we have

```
    @Bean
    public JobDetailFactoryBean fsPluginSendMessagesWorkerJob() {
        JobDetailFactoryBean obj = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
        obj.setJobClass(FSSendMessagesWorker.class);
        obj.setDurability(true);
        return obj;
    }


    @Bean
    @Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
    public SimpleTriggerFactoryBean fsPluginSendMessagesWorkerTrigger()

        SimpleTriggerFactoryBean obj = new SimpleTriggerFactoryBean();
        obj.setJobDetail(fsPluginSendMessagesWorkerJob().getObject());
        obj.setRepeatInterval("* * * 0 1");
        obj.setStartDelay(20000);
        return obj;
    }
```

After upgrading to Spring 5.3.x it looks like the all classes which extends QuartzBean and present in the .jar files could not be loaded while this was possible (worked) before in Spring 5.2.x
The ones present in the main app (.war) just works fain - are loaded.
Apart from Spring no other library was upgraded.

**021-10-05 14:03:25,055 [] [] [] [EE-ManagedExecutorService-quartzExecutorService-Thread-1] ERROR o.s.s.q.LocalDataSourceJobStore:2867 - Error retrieving job, setting trigger state to ERROR.
org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't retrieve job because a required class was not found: com.company.plugin.fs.worker.FSSendMessagesWorker from [Module "deployment.mycompany.war" from Service Module Loader]**
at deployment.mycompany.war//org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.retrieveJob(JobStoreSupport.java:1393)
at deployment.mycompany.war//org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.acquireNextTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:2864)
at deployment.mycompany.war//org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$41.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:2805)
at deployment.mycompany.war//org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$41.execute(JobStoreSupport.java:2803)
at deployment.mycompany.war//org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3864)
at deployment.mycompany.war//org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.acquireNextTriggers(JobStoreSupport.java:2802)
at deployment.mycompany.war//org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:287)
at org.jboss.as.ee@20.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ControlPointUtils$ControlledRunnable.run(ControlPointUtils.java:105)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.glassfish.javax.enterprise.concurrent//org.glassfish.enterprise.concurrent.internal.ManagedFutureTask.run(ManagedFutureTask.java:117)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
at org.glassfish.javax.enterprise.concurrent//org.glassfish.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThread.run(ManagedThreadFactoryImpl.java:227)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.company.plugin.fs.worker.FSSendMessagesWorker from [Module "deployment.mycompany.war" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
at deployment.domibus-MSH-wildfly-5.0-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:284)
at deployment.domibus-MSH-wildfly-5.0-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.ResourceLoaderClassLoadHelper.loadClass(ResourceLoaderClassLoadHelper.java:81)
at deployment.domibus-MSH-wildfly-5.0-SNAPSHOT.war//org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.ResourceLoaderClassLoadHelper.loadClass(ResourceLoaderClassLoadHelper.java:87)
at deployment.domibus-MSH-wildfly-5.0-SNAPSHOT.war//org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.selectJobDetail(StdJDBCDelegate.java:852)
at deployment.domibus-MSH-wildfly-5.0-SNAPSHOT.war//org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.retrieveJob(JobStoreSupport.java:1390)

Answer (score 0):

The quartz has the option to register class loader via the property:

```
 org.quartz.scheduler.classLoadHelper.class
```

In case setting the TCCL Transaction Context ClassLoader, make sure the cron thread has the same class loader as the class loader, which loads the "classes." In WildFly new threads, get ModuleClassLoader which can have different class scope than the one set back to thread scope in the initial stage.
Try with:
`org.quartz.scheduler.classLoadHelper.class = org.quartz.simpl.InitThreadContextClassLoadHelper`
Or write a custom ClassHelperLoader class.
https://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.2/org/quartz/spi/ClassLoadHelper.html